# com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The value is not set for the parameter number 3

Tags: java, sql-server, netbeans

I am facing the following error using NetBeans Java
**com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The value is not set for the parameter number 3.** My Code is as follows

**My Code**

```
public boolean SaveAllTeamsData(AllTeams allteams) throws SQLException{
String sql="select Team_ID,Team_Name,SnapShot_ID,SnapShot_Date from WM_ALLTEAMS where Team_ID=? and Team_Name=? and SnapShot_ID=? and SnapShot_Date=?";
try{
pst=Connect.c.prepareStatement(sql);
System.out.println(allteams.getAllTeam_id());
pst.setLong(1,allteams.getAllTeam_id());
System.out.println(snapshot_id);
pst.setLong(2,snapshot_id);
rs = pst.executeQuery();
if(rs.next())
{
allteamsRs=true;
}
else{
allteamsRs=false;
}
}catch(SQLException e){
System.out.println(e+"");
e.printStackTrace();
return false;
}finally{
pst.close();
rs.close();
```

}
**My Table**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WM_ALLTEAMS](
    [Team_ID] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [Team_Name] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [SnapShot_ID] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [SnapShot_Date] [varchar](max) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Though this question has been asked may times but could not find the solution. Help Required

Regards

Comment: You have 4 parameters (Team_ID=? and Team_Name=? and SnapShot_ID=? and SnapShot_Date=?) but only setting two of them (pst.setLong(1,allteams.getAllTeam_id()); and pst.setLong(2,snapshot_id);

Comment: Thank you---- This did helped me out... Great!!!